# c# windows form ( i want to update the data in the database )

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access

i want to update the password when i login with a user account 
like this 
i created an account the data saved to the data base then i want to change the data for the same account basically change the password for that account 
so i tried this

```
 public partial class User_Ditails : Form
{
    public OleDbConnection conect = new OleDbConnection();
    public User_Ditails()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        conect.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Mhamad\Desktop\form\Sign_Up.mdb;
                                        Persist Security Info=False;";
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OleDbDataAdapter ASDF = new OleDbDataAdapter ("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Sign_Up WHERE UserName='"+UserName.Text+"' AND Password='"+Old_Pass.Text+"'",conect);
        DataTable DS = new DataTable();
        ASDF.Fill(DS);
        errorProvider1.Clear();
        if (DS.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "1")
        {

            if (New_Pass.Text==Confirm_Pass.Text)
            {
                if (New_Pass.Text.Length > 6)
                {


                    OleDbDataAdapter cc = new OleDbDataAdapter("update Sign_Up set Password='" + New_Pass.Text + "' where UserName='" + UserName.Text + "' and Password='" + Old_Pass.Text + "'", conect);
                    DataTable DF = new DataTable();
                    cc.Fill(DF);
                    errorProvider1.Clear();

                    MessageBox.Show("Password Has Changed", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                }
                else
                {
                    errorProvider1.SetError(New_Pass, "Set Minimun 6 Charector");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                errorProvider1.SetError(New_Pass, "UnMatch Password");
                errorProvider1.SetError(Confirm_Pass, "UnMatch Password");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            errorProvider1.SetError(UserName,"Incorrect UserName");
            errorProvider1.SetError(Old_Pass, "Incorrect Password");

        }
```

but i always get this error

```
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'Syntax error in UPDATE statement.'
```

on this code cc.Fill(DF);

Comment: I don't see a problem with your update statement, but just in case you weren't aware the method you've used to create your update statement is extremely insecure and can be easily hacked. Please google 'what is SQL injection' to see why.

Comment: Let's try to write the query into a string with `string.Format()`. It will help you to write correct queries beacuse you can visualize better formatting errors.

Comment: @NibblyPig its just my collage project they said just create a simple one 
thanks for advice

Comment: Password is a reserved keyword for MS-Access. You need square brackets around it if you want to use it in a column name And you should ASAP learn how to use parameterized queries

Comment: Second advice. You don't need an OleDbDataAdapter for those commands. It is enough to use an OleDbCommand with the ExecuteScalar and the ExecuteNonQuery methods

Comment: @Steve thanks that work  i,m still new to programming there are not good methods for access data base so i watch sql there are diffrent thanks for helping

Comment: @JoKeRxbLaCk thank for helping too :)

Comment: Please read [Why do we always prefer using parameters in SQL statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505808/).

Comment: @DourHighArch thanks i will try to use them 
its kinda hard that parametars and im new